# Copying a value in an array to a variable

Tags: variables, random

I have an array of type int. It has one place and I want to copy that to a variable of type int.

Ex:

```
        Random randomNum = new Random();
        int myNumber = randomNum.Next(1,1000);

        int[] puterNumber = new int[1];
        puterNumber[ 1 ] = myNumber;
```

**Later in my code..**

```
        int myPuterNumber;

        myPuterNumber = puterNumber[ 1 ];
```

I get a message on mouseover saying 'Cannot resolve symbol 'puterNumber' '

Am I missing a step for copying the value of the array to an int variable?

Comment: Does "later in my code" mean "later on in the same method"? Or does it mean "in another method"? If the latter, the problem is that your array `puterNumber` is out of scope at the point you try to access it.

Comment: You're also going to get an index out of bounds error at runtime with this code. Java arrays index from 0, not 1.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a scope error, probably due to object structure if you are using Java. Honestly more code would help make it clear where exactly the problem was originating from.

Comment: +1 Never underestimate Javas ability to be pissy on casting and variable declaration.